Optometrist with deadly eye drops
I was telling my optometrist today about an old black and white movie on TCM that has a scene (I think it is the opening scene) of an optometrist that puts eye drops in someone's eyes saying:

This will not hurt.  

Within seconds the patient screams, holds his eyes and drops dead.  I thought it was an Orson Welles movie but now I am not sure. I saw it on Sunday Mar. 20 but I cannot remember if it was live on TCM or if it had been recorded previously and then I watched it that day. I only watched that scene so have few details except I remember that the room appeared rather dark and the eye dropper was made of glass with a long narrow point.  
What is this movie?

When did you see it? Where/when was it set? What did the victim/optometrist look like? .. The more details you can give, the more chance someone will be able to identify it.

I saw it on Sunday Mar. 20 but I cannot remember if it was live on TCM or if it had been recorded previously and then watched it that day.  I only watched that scene so have few details except I remember that the room appeared rather dark and the eye dropper was made of glass with a long narrow point.

It sounds a lot like Stanley Donen's 1966 thriller Arabesque with Gregory Peck and Sophia Loren. The film begins with the scene you described:

Professor Ragheeb (George Coulouris) is taken aback that his regular optometrist is not working, Sloane (John Merivale), a man who he has never met, taking his regular optometrist's place. During the eye examination, Sloane places drops in Ragheeb's eyes, blinding him in pain after a few seconds. After Ragheeb collapses and dies on the floor, Sloane takes off Ragheeb's glasses, and breaks them open to reveal a small piece of paper with crude drawings - seemingly hieroglyphics - on it.

The "doctor" uses a long eyedropper and says "You won't feel anything... That didn't hurt, did it?" The movie also aired on TCM in March 20 this year. The only problem really, is that it's in color. Here's the trailer:



